# Disable the side menu drawer in react native

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have created a page with sidemenu using the react-native and used the react-navigation for routing. I want to disable the sidemenu screen which is appearing through left slide side gesture.

```js
  export const StackNav = StackNavigator(
    {
      Login: {
        screen: Login,
        navigationOptions: {
          headerMode: "none",
          header: null
        }
      },
      Signup: {
        screen: Signup,
        navigationOptions: {
          headerMode: "none",
          header: null
        }
      },
    },
    {
      initialRouteName: "Login"
    }
  );

  //for admin login, run campaign
  const TabNav1 = TabNavigator(
    {
      SelectCarriers: {
        screen: SelectCarriers,
        navigationOptions: {
          tabBarLabel: "Select Carriers"
        }
      },
      ErrorRecords: {
        screen: ErrorRecords,
        navigationOptions: {
          tabBarLabel: "Error Records"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      tabBarPosition: "top",
      tabBarOptions: {
        labelStyle: {
          fontWeight: "bold"
        }
      }
    }
  );
  //for Notification page or carrier login
  const TabNav = TabNavigator(
    {
      Notification: {
        screen: Notification,
        navigationOptions: {
          tabBarLabel: "Notification"
        }
      },
      NotificationHistory: {
        screen: NotificationHistory,
        navigationOptions: {
          tabBarLabel: "Notification History"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      tabBarPosition: "bottom"
    }
  );
  const TabNavStack = StackNavigator({
    Main: {
      screen: TabNav,
      navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
        headerTitle: "Notification"
      })
    }
  });

  const sidemenuNav = StackNavigator({
    Dashboard: {
      screen: Dashboard,
      navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
        headerLeft: (
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.toggleDrawer()}>
            <Text style={{ paddingLeft: 15 }}>
              <Icon name="navicon" style={{ fontSize: 25 }} />
            </Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        )
      })
    },
    ViewRanking: {
      screen: ViewRanking,
      navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
        title: "View Ranking"
      })
    },
    SelectCarriers: {
      screen: SelectCarriers,
      navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
        headerTitle: "SELECT CARRIER"
      })
    },
    RunCampaign : {
      screen: RunCampaign,
      navigationOptions: ({navigation}) =>({
        title: "RUN"
      })
    },
    SelectedCampaign : {
      screen: SelectedCampaign,
      navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => ({
        title: "SELECTED CAMPAIGN",
      })
    },
    ChangePassword: {
      screen: ChangePassword,
      navigationOptions: {
        title: 'Change Password'
      }
    },
    EmailAnalytics: {
      screen: EmailAnalytics,
      navigationOptions: {
        title: 'Email Analytics'
      }
    },
    ViewCampaignHistory: {
      screen: ViewCampaignHistory,
      navigationOptions: {
        title: 'View Campaign History'
      }
    },
    CheckResponse: {
      screen: CheckResponse,
      navigationOptions: {
        title: 'CHECK RESPONSE'
      }
    },
    CampaignResult: {
      screen: CampaignResult,
      navigationOptions: {
        title: 'CAMPAIGN RESULT'
      }
    },
  });

  const DrawerNav = DrawerNavigator(
    {
      Item1: {
        screen: sidemenuNav
      }
    },
    {
      contentComponent: SideMenu,
      drawerWidth: Dimensions.get("window").width - 120
    }
  );

  export const PrimaryNav = StackNavigator(
    {
      StackNav: { screen: StackNav },
      TabNavStack: { screen: TabNavStack },
      DrawerNav: { screen: DrawerNav }
    },
    {
      // Default config for all screens
      headerMode: "none",
      initialRouteName: "StackNav"
    }
  );
```

So, here in the sidemenuNav, i want to disable the side drawer for ViewRanking, SelectCarriers....

I have tried `drawerLockMode` with navigation options but not worked.

i have referred some issues but no use.

After suggesting the answer mark it as duplicate or vote down

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`drawerLockMode` is the option you are finding. [Doc](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/drawer-navigator.html#drawerlockmode)  (No drawerLockedMode)

> Specifies the lock mode of the drawer. This can also update dynamically by using screenProps.drawerLockMode on your top level router.

And there are three types option. [Doc](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/drawerlayoutandroid.html#drawerlockmode)

- unlocked (default), meaning that the drawer will respond (open/close) to touch gestures.
- locked-closed, meaning that the drawer will stay closed and not respond to gestures.
- locked-open, meaning that the drawer will stay opened and not respond to gestures. The drawer may still be opened and closed programmatically (openDrawer/closeDrawer).

Thus, add conditional statement in navigationOptions of your `sidemenuNav`. [Doc](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-options-resolution.html#a-drawer-has-a-stack-inside-of-it-and-you-want-to-lock-the-drawer-on-certain-screens)

```
sidemenuNav.navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
  let drawerLockMode = 'unlocked';
  if (navigation.state.index > 0) { // control by depth
    drawerLockMode = 'locked-closed';
  }

  return {
    drawerLockMode,
  };
};
```

And this is my tested code.

```js
const AuthStackNavigation = createStackNavigator({
  HomeStack: HomeScreen,
  LoginStack: HomeScreen,
  RegisterStack: HomeScreen,
}, {
  initialRouteName: 'HomeStack',
  navigationOptions: {
    gesturesEnabled: false,
  },
})

AuthStackNavigation.navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
  let drawerLockMode = 'unlocked';
  if (navigation.state.key > 0) {
    drawerLockMode = 'locked-closed';
  }

  return {
    drawerLockMode,
  };
};

const DashboardStack = createStackNavigator({
  Dashboard: {
    screen: Dashboard,
  }
})

const DrawerNav = createDrawerNavigator({
  AuthStackNavigation: {
    screen: AuthStackNavigation,
    // navigationOptions: {
    //   gesturesEnabled: false,
    //   drawerLockMode: 'locked-close'
    // }
  },
  DashboardStack: {
    screen: DashboardStack,
  },
  ThirdScreen: Dashboard,
})

...

const MainNavigation = createSwitchNavigator({
  HomeDrawer: DrawerNav,
 Tab: TabNavigationComponent,
  AuthStack: AuthStackNavigation, // You will use this.props.navigation.replace('HomeDrawer') after login process.
})

export default MainNavigation // Stack, Drawer, Switch naviagtions return react component.
```

Added

I totally tested with your screen architect and checked it worked well.

```js
/**
 * Disable the side menu drawer in react native
 * Test code: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52968354/disable-the-side-menu-drawer-in-react-native/52970168?noredirect=1#comment92875031_52970168
 *
 */

import {
  createStackNavigator,
 createDrawerNavigator,
 createBottomTabNavigator,
} from 'react-navigation';

import { Platform, TouchableOpacity, Text } from 'react-native';
import React from 'react';


import HomeScreen from './Home';
import Dashboard from './Dashboard';
import CheckBoxScreen from './CheckBoxTest';

import TabBar from './TabBar';
// import createBottomTabNavigator from 'react-navigation-tabs/dist/utils/createBottomTabNavigator';

export const StackNav = createStackNavigator(
 {
  Login: {
   screen: HomeScreen,
   navigationOptions: {
    headerMode: "none",
    header: null
   }
  },
  Signup: {
   screen: HomeScreen,
   navigationOptions: {
    headerMode: "none",
    header: null
   }
  },
 },
 {
  initialRouteName: "Login"
 }
);

//for admin login, run campaign
const TabNav1 = createBottomTabNavigator(
 {
  SelectCarriers: {
   screen: HomeScreen,
   navigationOptions: {
    tabBarLabel: "Select Carriers"
   }
  },
  ErrorRecords: {
   screen: HomeScreen,
   navigationOptions: {
    tabBarLabel: "Error Records"
   }
  }
 },
 {
  tabBarPosition: "top",
  tabBarOptions: {
   labelStyle: {
    fontWeight: "bold"
   }
  }
 }
);
//for Notification page or carrier login
const TabNav = createBottomTabNavigator(
 {
  Notification: {
   screen: Dashboard,
   navigationOptions: {
    tabBarLabel: "Notification"
   }
  },
  NotificationHistory: {
   screen: Dashboard,
   navigationOptions: {
    tabBarLabel: "Notification History"
   }
  }
 },
 {
  tabBarPosition: "bottom"
 }
);
const TabNavStack = createStackNavigator({
 Main: {
  screen: TabNav,
  navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
   headerTitle: "Notification"
  })
 }
});

const sidemenuNav = createStackNavigator({
 Dashboard: {
  screen: HomeScreen,
  navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
   headerLeft: (
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.toggleDrawer()}>
     <Text style={{ paddingLeft: 15 }}>
      {/* <Icon name="navicon" style={{ fontSize: 25 }} /> */}
      icon
     </Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
   )
  })
 },
 LoginStack: {
  screen: Dashboard,
  navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
   title: "View Ranking"
  })
 },
 SelectCarriers: {
  screen: Dashboard,
  navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
   headerTitle: "SELECT CARRIER"
  })
 },
 RunCampaign : {
  screen: Dashboard,
  navigationOptions: ({navigation}) =>({
   title: "RUN"
  })
 },
 SelectedCampaign : {
  screen: Dashboard,
  navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => ({
   title: "SELECTED CAMPAIGN",
  })
 },
 ChangePassword: {
  screen: Dashboard,
  navigationOptions: {
   title: 'Change Password'
  }
 },
 EmailAnalytics: {
  screen: Dashboard,
  navigationOptions: {
   title: 'Email Analytics'
  }
 },
 ViewCampaignHistory: {
  screen: Dashboard,
  navigationOptions: {
   title: 'View Campaign History'
  }
 },
 CheckResponse: {
  screen: Dashboard,
  navigationOptions: {
   title: 'CHECK RESPONSE'
  }
 },
 CampaignResult: {
  screen: Dashboard,
  navigationOptions: {
   title: 'CAMPAIGN RESULT'
  }
 },
}, {
 navigationOptions: {
    gesturesEnabled: false,
    // drawerLockMode: 'locked-closed' // not work
  },
});

sidemenuNav.navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
  let drawerLockMode = 'unlocked';
  if (navigation.state.index > 0) { // control by depth
    drawerLockMode = 'locked-closed';
  }

  return {
    drawerLockMode,
  };
};


const DrawerNav = createDrawerNavigator(
 {
  Item1: {
   screen: sidemenuNav
  }
 },
 {
  // contentComponent: SideMenu,
  // drawerWidth: Dimensions.get("window").width - 120
 }
);

export const PrimaryNav = createStackNavigator(
 {
  StackNav: { screen: StackNav },
  TabNavStack: { screen: TabNavStack },
  DrawerNav: { screen: DrawerNav }
 },
 {
  // Default config for all screens
  headerMode: "none",
  initialRouteName: "DrawerNav"
 }
);

export default PrimaryNav // Stack, Drawer, Switch naviagtions return react component.
```

I am not sure what is wrong in your code but use recent react-navigation with recommend methods as `createSomeNavigator` instead of deprecated as `DrawerNavigator`, `StackNavigator` and so on. 
Good luck.

Comment: I am not sure you used `drawerLockedMode` or `drawerLockMode`. Try again to use static navigationOptions in your screen component as my answer.

Comment: I have used drawerLockMode, by mistake it was as drawerLockedMode. I already seen and followed the above given suggestion, but not work, so I posted here with code where and how to implement. Sorry to say, but atleast a suggestion rather than such doc.

Comment: @NitinAgarwal I updated my answer after testing. And it will be better to show how to apply `drawerLockMode` to your code if my answer is not work.

Comment: @NitinAgarwal And you know, the checking typo was priority option for me before testing your code. Some questions are easily solved by fixing typos. :)

Comment: Thanks @Jeff Gu Kang. I know the checking typo is priority but, its not working, its not even navigating, I already tried it. Just a help, may be I am placing it in wrong place, can you place the code with your suggestion, so I can try better.

Comment: @NitinAgarwal I added my tested code. I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks @Jeff Gu Kang for all your efforts, but its not working.

Comment: @NitinAgarwal And react-navigation's version is "^2.18.1". I will test again using dummy code same as yours tomorrow. I do not know why it is not work on yours. :(

Comment: Thanks @Jeff Gu kang, i am using react navigation 2.17.0 and please it will be great help if its done, by the time i will try here.

Comment: @NitinAgarwal I tested using your code and it works well. Check the answer.

Comment: Lots of Thanks @Jeff Gu Kang, it really working great. Thanks for spending time for my issue.

Comment: @NitinAgarwal My pleasure. :)

Comment: if you're like me, and you need only one screen in a stack to have a disabled drawer, then this is the solution for you. need to use a function with conditional logic to set the `drawerLockMode`